# Localization - how to name resource file so asp.net mvc will find it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a resource file named: Res.en-US.resx, however, I cannot access the resources from code.  When I rename the file to Res_en-US.resx, I am able to access it via: Res_en_US in code:

```
var someString = Res_en_US.SomeString;
```

[this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/183/Globalization-And-Localization-With-Razor-Web-Pages) article claims I can include a "." and a "-" in the resource file name:

> A French resource file can be created by copying the English one, and
>   renaming the result TestResource.fr-FR.resx.

However, this article is also using some special resource folder and not ASP.NET MVC.  I want asp.net to pick the correct resource file automatically based on the user's HTTP header, but I don't see how to do that if I can't name the file correctly.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my projects i put the files in App_GlobalResources this folder is at the same level as Controllers, Models and Views in my project.

In my latest project the files are simply named as follows

```
Localization.resx
Localization.en-US.resx
Localization.fr-FR.resx
Localization.ru-RU.resx
```

They are declared as Public in the resource editor.

and I reference the text like this in views

@Localization.WelcomeText;